# Error while trying to connect to SQLite3 database from CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Recently I migrate an application from one server to another and now when I try to access to the app I get this error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/reynierpm/magno-reynierpm/models/datasources/dbo/dbo_sqlite3.php on line 144" can any tell me why or where it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got your `dbo_sqlite3.php` from. As far as I can tell the "official" one never called a `query()` method on line 144 and has proper exception handling to prevent this kind of error surfacing when a database connection cannot be established.

- The `new PDO()` call always [returns a `PDO` object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-returnvalues).
- Unless the connection fails, then it [throws a `PDOException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-errors).
- The latest datasource [catches that exception](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/3574bab98f9bdc60ffa5f86d3c08e4a96d664b54/models/datasources/dbo/dbo_sqlite3.php#L171).
- PDO objects [have a `query()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) (which solves your problem).

I would advise updating that file to the [latest version](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/master/models/datasources/dbo/dbo_sqlite3.php).